# How to get collisions of collisions in unity2d? And what is wrong with this code?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

i have circle gameobject prefabs. i instantiate them randomly about 50-100 times. i added rigidbodies to them and they move around. the issue is that; i want to destroy a group of these prefabs which have the same tag and collide with each other. but i cant get all colliders of them. because some of them collides with 2nd or 3rd prefabs. how can i get them without collide them?

refrance image of what i want to do

[image]

> i try to do it with this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Colliders : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<GameObject> colliders;
     
    private void Start() {
        if (colliders == null)
            colliders = new List<GameObject>();

        colliders.Add(this.gameObject);
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag != this.gameObject.tag) return;  // if colliders haven't the same tag ignore
        if (colliders.Contains(col.gameObject)) return;         // if colliders already exist in the list ignore
        colliders.Add(col.gameObject);                          // add colliders to the list

        if (colliders.Count < 2) return;                        // if there aren't more than two gameobjects in the list ignore

        for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Count; i++)               // get all colliders in the list
        {
            if (colliders[i] == this.gameObject) return;        // if it is same as this gameobject ignore
            if (colliders[i] == col.gameObject) return;         // if it is same as this collider ignore

            Colliders colScript = col.gameObject.GetComponent<Colliders>();   // get the collider script attached to the colliders in the list
            List<GameObject> colColliders = colScript.colliders;            // get the list of the colliders in the list

            for (int j = 0; j < colColliders.Count; j++)
            {
                if (colliders.Contains(colColliders[j])) return;           // if colliders already exist in the list ignore
                colliders.Add(colColliders[j]);                            // add colliders to the list
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D col) {
        for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Count; i++)               // get all colliders in the list
        {
            if (colliders[i] == this.gameObject) return;        // if it is same as this gameobject ignore

            Colliders colScript = col.gameObject.GetComponent<Colliders>();   // get the collider script attached to the colliders in the list
            List<GameObject> colColliders = colScript.colliders;            // get the list of the colliders in the list

            for (int j = 0; j < colColliders.Count; j++)
            {
                if (!colliders.Contains(colColliders[j])) return;           // if colliders not exist in the list ignore
                colliders.Remove(colColliders[j]);                          // remove colliders from the list
            }
        }

        if (col.gameObject.tag != this.gameObject.tag) return;  // if colliders haven't the same tag ignore
        if (!colliders.Contains(col.gameObject)) return;         // if colliders not exist in the list ignore
        colliders.Remove(col.gameObject);                          // remove colliders from the list
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you now only check the tag **after** removing everything in the `OnTriggerExit`?

Comment: i see that and fixed but about 5-7 hours i have worked on this project and i wrote this properly before. it didnt give coding errors. but i couldnt get all colliders. this code is just to show you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the collision detection through the method [`OnCollisionStay2D(Collision collisionInfo)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay.html). If you get a reference to what you have collided with, you could call a method on the collided object to get what it has collided with, get the reference to what they have collided with, and destroy the gameObject.

Hope this helps!

Comment: right here i have a problem. A is collided with B. but A is not collided with C and D. if i destroy A and others collided with it, A and B is deleted only. i can get colliders of A. how can i get colliders of B which is collided with A?

Comment: Add a script (that has a method to return the objects it is colliding with) to the things you are colliding with, then when you collide with that one object use the reference call that method that will return the objects that the second object it colliding with, then delete all of them.

Comment: Something like `references = collisionInfo.GetComponent<MyClass>().myMethod()`, then `Destroy(collisionInfo.gameObject)` and `Destroy(references.gameObject)`. This is pseudocode though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to forward the other collisions somehow.

For example store the collisions `OnCollisionEnter` and remove them `OnCollisionExit`. If all obects do that you can than get the collisions of all objects you are currently colliding with etc.

Might look like e.g.

```c#
public class CollisionDetection : MonoBehaviour
{
    // List for storing current collisions 
    // (the references of the Collisions component of colliding objects to be exact)
    public List<CollisionDetection> collisions = new List<CollisionDetection>();

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        // however you want to check the collisions
        if(other.tag != "XY") return;

        // Try to get the CollisionDetection component
        // Note depending on your collider setup you might
        // have to use GetComponentInChildren or GetComponentInParent instead
        var collComponent = other.gameObject.GetComponent<CollisionDetection>();

        // If no Collisions component found do nothing
        if(!collComponent) return;

        // If this Collisions component is already in the list do nothing
        if(collisions.Contains(collComponent)) return;

        // Add the reference to the list 
        collisions.Add(collComponent);


        // probably some check if you want to call destroy
        if(! .... ) return;

        // Careful this should be called only by one of the objects
        DestroyCollisions(new List<CollisionDetection>(){this});
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
    {
        // however you want to check the collisions
        if(other.tag != "XY") return;

        // Try to get the CollisionDetection component
        // same as before you might have to use
        // GetComponentInChildren or GetComponentInParent
        var collComponent = other.gameObject.GetComponent<CollisionDetection>();

        // If no Collisions component found do nothing
        if(!collComponent) return;

        // If list doesn't contain the reference do nothing
        if(!collisions.Contains(collComponent)) return;

         // Remove reference from the list   
        collisions.Remove(collComponent);
    }

    // pass a parameter in order to not destroy the original callers objects to early
    public void DestroyCollisions(List<CollisionDetection> originalCallers)
    {
        // Now when you destroy objects check for other collisions recursiv
        foreach(var collision in collisions)
        {
            // Don't destroy the original callers since they will destroy themselves when done
            if(originalCallers.Contains(collision)) continue;

            // it is possible that two objects collide with the same other object
            // so they try to destroy the same object twice -> exception
            // So if one reference is null already skip
            if(!collision) continue;

            // Maybe another check? E.g. is color equal? etc
            if(! ...) continue;

            // Add to original callers to not destroy it to early
            originalCallers.Add(collision);

            // Destroy also this collision's collisions
            collision.DestroyCollisions(originalCallers);
        }

        // Finally destroy this object itself

        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

How you fill those `if` tags, making all calls secure etc is your task.

No warranties though since I hacked this in on my smartphone ;) but I hope you get the idea

---

**Update**

For not destroying the objects but just collect them in a list you could do

```
public List<CollisionDetection> FetchCollisions()
{
    var output = new List<CollisionDetection>();
    output.Add(this);

    // check for other collisions recursiv
    foreach(var collision in collisions)
    {

        foreach(var col in collision.FetchCollisions())
        {
            if(output.Contains(col)) continue;
            output.Add(col);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use it but it gave a bunch of errors. (note: i edited everything to fit my game there was no problem) isnt this code c#? i have 5 different object prefabs. and i spawn them randomly. i want the prefab to control other prefabs near it which have same tag and add them to a list (i did it) then find the prefabs near the prefabs which are near of it and add them also thr same list.(here is where i stuck)

Comment: What errors do you get? And "near" is not the same as "collide". Ofcourse you could instead of destroying the objects add them all to one list.

Comment: i edited all the question and added referance image and code

Comment: I still don't see what errors you get with my code? Instead of calling `Destroy` you could change the method and collect them all in a list

Comment: you wrote it for 3d. i cant fix it to 2d. there is no "Collisions" method in unity2d. i made it List<Collision>. and because of this i couldnt play the game "List<Collisions>(){this})" unity gives error for the "this".

Comment: my `Collions` could be **any** other classname like e.g. `CollisionDetection` or `MyFancyCollisionBehaviour` ... whatever name you give it ofcourse the typename of the classlist has to match `List<MyFancyCollisionBehaviour>`. The only thing you should have to change for `2d` is call the two functions `OnCollisionEnter2D` and `OnCollisionExit2D` that's all. .. `Collision` is a quite bad classname because it already exists in Unity.

Comment: thank you for your help dude. but this code isn't work with unity2d c# script. a list should be a object in the unity. List<MyFancyCollisionBehaviour> gives error. do you mean the "Collision2D" or "Collider2D" ? and did you test this code?

Comment: No I did not .. but I do **not** mean `Collision` nor `Collision2D` .. what I am storing there is not the reference to the collision but to the `MonoBehaviour` component itself. And yes you have to change `OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)` to `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)` and the same for exit

Comment: okay now i understand. so, why you list scripts of other collisions instead of listing their lists in their scripts? because i did so. is it a bad way?

Comment: Because on this way I have access on the third and fourth collision etc